# Is it possible to refresh Select objects in Selenium when testing ajax

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I was working on my selenium tests, I ran into an issue when I was testing some ajax functionality on a website.  I was getting an error `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM`.

After looking up a bunch of stuff, I know the reason that I am getting this error is because the element that I am accessing in my first select object is considered since the ajax reloaded that section of the site.

In order to get around this exception, I just created a new select object each time.  The xpath does not change when the page is reloaded.

Is it possible to just refresh the Select with the new xpath to the object, instead of creating a new one each time?

Thanks for the help.

```
public static boolean ajaxFunctionalityFF() throws InterruptedException {

    int rowCount=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='classname']/tbody/tr")).size();
    rowSizes.add(rowCount);
    Select ajaxSelector = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("edit-term")));


    ajaxSelector.selectByVisibleText("-Beef);
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    rowCount=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='classname']/tbody/tr")).size();
    rowSizes.add(rowCount);
    totalElements = totalElements + rowCount;

    Select ajaxSelector2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("edit-term"))); //create a new one to fix the stale element exception
    ajaxSelector2.selectByVisibleText("-Cattle");
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    rowCount=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='classname']/tbody/tr")).size();
```

Comment: Did you try giving explicit/fluent waits and see if you can use the same select element ? Also when you say page section is getting refreshed, does it mean your select element is getting refreshed too?

Comment: Not explicit/fluent waits, but I did litter the entire method with `Thread.Sleep()` just seeing if there would be any change in state.  The select element is getting refreshed in the sense that it is populated with a new value, but it is still the same xpath.  Its a drop down list, and the `selectByVisibleText` is just selecting different options in there.

Comment: Then you should probably try waiting for the element using fluent waits after selecting your first option. Try this - `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("edit-term")));`. Let me know if it still doesn't work. Also check [fluent-wait example](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9636/using-fluentwait-class-to-wait-until-a-condition-is-true-in-selenium-webdriver).

Comment: Replacing the ajaxSelector2 causes with the fluent wait causes the same error as before about the reference being stale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to fetch it each time that section of the HTML is refreshed. I would do something like

```
private By selectLocator = By.id("edit-term");
public static boolean ajaxFunctionalityFF() throws InterruptedException
{
    ...
    Select ajaxSelector = getSelect();
    ...
    ajaxSelector = getSelect();
    ajaxSelector.selectByVisibleText("-Cattle");
    ...
}
public static Select getSelect()
{
    return new Select(driver.findElement(selectLocator));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One workaround that i usually use for such cases is as below:

```
do
{
try
{
    WebElement element=FindThatElement;
    element.performSomeAction();
    break;
}
catch(StaleElementException | //Any Other unExpectedException e)
{
    //continue do while loop;
}
} while(1>0);
```

Comment: Thanks, ill be sure to keep it in mind if it happens again.